# PHP - EXEC || Ejecutar jar con argumentos con caracteres especiales

Tags: php, java, linux, jar, exec

Estoy tratando de ejecutar un archivo har desde "shell_exec", funciona bien pero cuando los datos contienen caracteres especiales (áúíó ñ) aparece "�����������" jar envía un servicio web y este extraño los símbolos no dicen nada ..

¿Cómo puedo codificar o decodificar el mensaje para el comando "exec" para mantener intacto el mensaje del archivo jar? Intenté convertir utf-8 e ISO-8859-1 pero no tuve éxito gracias y saludos. --- SERVIDOR RET HAT RHEL 8.

```
 <?php
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $apellido = $_POST["apellido"];
    $correo = $_POST["correo"];
    $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
    $comentarios = $_POST["comentarios"];
    $subject = $_POST["servicio"];
    $pais = $_POST["pais"];
    $region = $_POST["region"];
    $ciudad = $_POST["ciudad"];     
    $empresa = $_POST["empresa"];
    $lenguaje = $_POST["lenguaje"];
    $movil = $_POST["movil"];
    $empresa2 = '';
    $TicketID = $_POST["TicketID"];

    if(empty($empresa)){
        $empresa = $nombre.' '.$apellido;
    }

  // $comentarios = "<![CDATA[" . preg_replace("<\n>", "", nl2br($comentarios)) . "]]>";
  $comentarios = preg_replace("<\n>", "", nl2br($comentarios));


$response  = shell_exec('java -jar Centelsa.jar '
                        . '"' . $empresa . '" ' 
                        . '"' . $empresa2 . '" ' 
                        . '"' . $lenguaje . '" ' 
                        . '"' . $correo . '" ' 
                        . '"' . $pais . '" ' 
                        . '"' . $region . '" ' 
                        . '"' . $ciudad . '" ' 
                        . '"' . $nombre . '" ' 
                        . '"' . $apellido . '" ' 
                        . '"' . $telefono . '" ' 
                        . '"' . $movil . '" ' 
                        . '"' . $subject . '" ' 
                        . '"' . $comentarios . '" ' 
                        . '"' . $TicketID . '"' );
echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné agregando estas lineas de código, aunque la maquina de linux ya estaba configurada UTF-8, al enviar los datos desde el php mediante el exec, se enviaba en un formato "ANSI" lo cual pude comprobar ejecutanto

```
echo exec('locale charmap');
```

Entonces lo que hice fue al inicio del PHP agregar esta codigicacion y al imprimir el charmap ahora si pude obtener UTF-8.

```
$locale='en_US.UTF-8';
setlocale(LC_ALL,$locale);
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
echo exec('locale charmap');
```

Espero que esto le pueda servir a alguien más. saludos